# Loading Of Multiple Images ( Android studio - Glide )

Tags: java, image, loops, android-glide

*this question may sound dumb or irrelevant **- but i would love to learn the way this problem will be solved***

**Surface Coverage Of The Working Of App :**
The Data Being Displayed On The Screen Is Dynamic , And Is Displayed In a Loop , The Images Are Also Being Loaded During the Loop - **the URL for image and rest data is dynamically received**

**Problem :**
Multiple Images Are Getting Loaded Slowly

**Detailed View Of The Problem**
The Images Are Being Fetched From Github And I'm using glide library to load the images from the url ... the images are getting loaded fast when connected to a **high-speed Wi-Fi** but when speed is reduced to the **average download speed of mobile networks** it takes a long time while loading the images

**PS- its a dumb question but would need this problem to be solved**

**Code Snippet :**

```
loop
{
  ........

  Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(link[c]).centerCrop().placeholder(drawable)
       .into(imb);

  ........
}
```

**I tried Using cache Method ( memory&disk ) and preloading**
but it only works when the image is loaded at-least one ( on a fast network )

**--------------------------**

## **if the answer to this problem is something around lazy load / progressive loading of images , then please give a detailed answer below**

**--------------------------**

*not sure whether the change should be done in the code or the way the image is accessed or from where it is accessed*

All I need to know is **how do i load multiple images faster on a slower network** using *glide or any other library* ...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're bound by the network speed and the size of the images, not by the library.

The only solution that I can think of is to try to make your images smaller (e.g. a format with better compression, use a lower dpi, etc.).

Comment: thanks..i have found the solution by loading a low quality and low size .jpg image as the thumbnail using the glide library...